# Implementing and testing WebSocket server connection timeout

Tags: python, tornado

I am implementing a WebSockets server in Tornado 3.2.  The client connecting to the server won't be a browser.

For cases in which there is back-and-forth communication between server and client, I would like to add a max. time the server will wait for a client response before closing the connection.

This is roughly what I've been trying:

```
import datetime
import tornado

class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.timeout = None

    def _close_on_timeout(self):
        if self.ws_connection:
            self.close()

    def open(self):
        initialize()

    def on_message(self, message):
        # Remove previous timeout, if one exists.
        if self.timeout:
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().remove_timeout(self.timeout)
            self.timeout = None

        if is_last_message:
            self.write_message(message)
            self.close()
        else:
            # Add a new timeout.
            self.timeout = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(
                datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1000), self._close_on_timeout)
            self.write_message(message)
```

Am I being a klutz and is there a much simpler way of doing this?  I can't even seem to schedule a simple print statement via add_timeout above.

I also need some help testing this.  This is what I have so far:

```
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test
import time

class WSTests(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    @gen_test
    def test_long_response(self):
        ws = yield websocket_connect('ws://address', io_loop=self.io_loop)

        # First round trip.
        ws.write_message('First message.')
        result = yield ws.read_message()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'First response.')

        # Wait longer than the timeout.
        # The test is in its own IOLoop, so a blocking sleep should be okay?
        time.sleep(1.1)

        # Expect either write or read to fail because of a closed socket.
        ws.write_message('Second message.')
        result = yield ws.read_message()

        self.assertNotEqual(result, 'Second response.')
```

The client has no problem writing to and reading from the socket.  This is presumably because the add_timeout isn't firing.

Does the test need to yield somehow to allow the timeout callback on the server to run?  I would have thought not since the docs say the tests run in their own IOLoop.

**Edit**

This is the working version, per Ben's suggestions.

```
import datetime
import tornado

class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.timeout = None

    def _close_on_timeout(self):
        if self.ws_connection:
            self.close()

    def open(self):
        initialize()

    def on_message(self, message):
        # Remove previous timeout, if one exists.
        if self.timeout:
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().remove_timeout(self.timeout)
            self.timeout = None

        if is_last_message:
            self.write_message(message)
            self.close()
        else:
            # Add a new timeout.
            self.timeout = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(
                datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1000), self._close_on_timeout)
            self.write_message(message)
```

The test:

```
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test
import time

class WSTests(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    @gen_test
    def test_long_response(self):
        ws = yield websocket_connect('ws://address', io_loop=self.io_loop)

        # First round trip.
        ws.write_message('First message.')
        result = yield ws.read_message()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'First response.')

        # Wait a little more than the timeout.
        yield gen.Task(self.io_loop.add_timeout, datetime.timedelta(seconds=1.1))

        # Expect either write or read to fail because of a closed socket.
        ws.write_message('Second message.')
        result = yield ws.read_message()
        self.assertEqual(result, None)
```

Comment: Thank you for your working version. That was a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout-handling code in your first example looks correct to me.

For testing, each test case gets its own IOLoop, but there is only one IOLoop for both the test and anything else it runs, so you must use add_timeout instead of time.sleep() here as well to avoid blocking the server.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Added an edit above to show what I'm trying. The test timeout callback runs, but the timeout callback in the handler still isn't firing. Am I starting the IOLoop correctly?

Comment: If you're using `@gen_test`, it will take care of starting/stopping the IOLoop for you, so you should remove the last two lines of the updated test.  In a coroutine, you probably want to use `yield gen.Task(self.io_loop.add_timeout, timedelta(seconds=1.1))` instead of passing a callback to add_timeout.  Mixing coroutines and callbacks can be tricky (here, you'd need to decorate `_check` with `@gen.coroutine` and use `io_loop.add_future` to schedule it)

Comment: Ben, I'm sorry for being dense. I made the changes, and sure enough, the test now waits the right amount of time. However, the server's timeout callback is still not called, and the test can read and write to the socket after waiting for 1.1 seconds. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to use IOLoop.current(), not IOLoop.instance().

Answer (score 2):

Ey Ben, I know this question was long ago resolved, but I wanted to share with any user reading this the solution I made for this. 
It's basically based on yours, but it solves the problem from an external Service that can be easily integrated within any websocket using composition instead of inheritance:

```
class TimeoutWebSocketService():
    _default_timeout_delta_ms = 10 * 60 * 1000  # 10 min

    def __init__(self, websocket, ioloop=None, timeout=None):
        # Timeout
        self.ioloop = ioloop or tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        self.websocket = websocket
        self._timeout = None
        self._timeout_delta_ms = timeout or TimeoutWebSocketService._default_timeout_delta_ms

    def _close_on_timeout(self):
        self._timeout = None
        if self.websocket.ws_connection:
            self.websocket.close()

    def refresh_timeout(self, timeout=None):
        timeout = timeout or self._timeout_delta_ms
        if timeout > 0:
            # Clean last timeout, if one exists
            self.clean_timeout()

            # Add a new timeout (must be None from clean).
            self._timeout = self.ioloop.add_timeout(
                datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=timeout), self._close_on_timeout)

    def clean_timeout(self):
        if self._timeout is not None:
            # Remove previous timeout, if one exists.
            self.ioloop.remove_timeout(self._timeout)
            self._timeout = None
```

In order to use the service, itś as easy as create a new TimeoutWebService instance (optionally with the timeout in ms, as well as the ioloop where it should be executed) and call the method ''refresh_timeout'' to either set the timeout for the first time or reset an already existing timeout, or ''clean_timeout'' to stop the timeout service.

```
class BaseWebSocketHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.timeout_service = TimeoutWebSocketService(timeout=(1000*60))

        ## Optionally starts the service here 
        self.timeout_service.refresh_timeout()

        ## rest of prepare method 

    def on_message(self):
        self.timeout_service.refresh_timeout()

    def on_close(self):
        self.timeout_service.clean_timeout()
```

Thanks to this approach, you can control when exactly and under which conditions you want to restart the timeout which might differ from app to app. As an example you might only want to  refresh the timeout if user acomplish X conditions, or if the message is the expected one.

I hope ppl enjoy this solution !