# How to automatically close connection serverside after a certain time in Tornado Websocket

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a Tornado Websocket server which has a dictionary of open connections:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self, *args):
        self.id = self.generate_id()
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)

        # ... DO STUFF ...

        clients[self.id] = {"id": self.id, "time":datetime.now(), "object": self}
        self.write_message("Connection SUCCESSFUL! Thanks for connecting! Your connection ID is: %d :)" % self.id)
        print datetime.now()
        print "New connection. ID: %d" % self.id
        print "Total number of open connections: %d" % len(clients)

    def on_close(self):
        print datetime.now()
        print "Closing connection %d." % self.id 
        if self.id in clients:
            del clients[self.id]
        print "Number of open connections: %d" % len(clients)
```

I would like to do automatically close all connections which are more than one hour old. So something like this:

```
for client in clients.values():
    if (datetime.now() - client["time"])>timedelta(minutes=60):
        client["object"].close()
```

But I don't know where I should put this check and closing old connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980962/implementing-and-testing-websocket-server-connection-timeout) for further clarification

```
import tornado
import datetime
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self, *args):
        self.id = self.generate_id()
        self.stream.set_nodelay(True)
        self.timeout = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_timeout(
            datetime.timedelta(minutes=60), self.explicit_close)

        # ... DO STUFF ...

        clients[self.id] = {"id": self.id, "time":datetime.now(), "object": self}
        self.write_message("Connection SUCCESSFUL! Thanks for connecting! Your connection ID is: %d :)" % self.id)
        print datetime.now()
        print "New connection. ID: %d" % self.id
        print "Total number of open connections: %d" % len(clients)

    def on_close(self):
        print datetime.now()
        print "Closing connection %d." % self.id 
        if self.id in clients:
            del clients[self.id]
        print "Number of open connections: %d" % len(clients)

    def explicit_close(self):
        self.close() # you wont even have to iterate over the clients.
```

> Follow the [IOLoop](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html) of tornado and [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980962/implementing-and-testing-websocket-server-connection-timeout) it will be easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks! That looks great. I'll test it and let you know the result.

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse sure... also check that link i have mentioned... it has a detailed descussion

Comment: So I implemented it, but it is not working properly. I made another question for the problem (which is that connections aren't closed when they should be): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424881/python-tornado-websocket-connections-still-open-after-being-closed