# Silently closing websockets in Tornado

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, tornado

I have an nginx-server with one-hour timeout and a Tornado web-server behind it.

When nginx closes the connection, I have no idea about it in Tornado. I saw this question about closing connections automatically by timeout-event ([Implementing and testing WebSocket server connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980962/implementing-and-testing-websocket-server-connection-timeout)) and I'm going to use it as a fallback workaround.

**My question is**: does the Tornado have an internal mechanism for websocket connections invalidation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebSocketHandler` has an overridable [`on_close`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.on_close) method, which should be getting called when the connection is closed (most of the time). This method is not 100% reliable (due to the limitations of the underlying network protocols), however, so a timeout-based fallback is recommended. Tornado doesn't have any built-in support for this, though, so you'll have to implement it yourself, perhaps in a manner similar to the answer you linked to.

Comment: also ping (http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.ping) could be good to implement this without timeout, but in "closed unexpectedly " aware manner

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about underlying network protocol limitations. Browser's websocket gets onClose event even in case of problem on underlying network level (e.g. server got kill signal). I'd tested this case on browser's side. Therefore I think it's Tornado-specific issue.

Comment: "Server got kill signal" is not a network-level problem. Try unplugging an ethernet cable.